# Azure Key Vault WARN okhttp3.OkHttpClient: A connection was leaked

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, encryption, azure-keyvault

We are encrypting SQL Server DB columns using Azure Key Vault Provider in our Spring boot application and everything works fine. However, we see "connection leaked" Warning message being logged which as follows:

```
2019-12-04 16:26:26.332  WARN 1 --- [ ConnectionPool] okhttp3.OkHttpClient                     : A connection to https://xxxxx.vault.azure.net/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?  java.lang.Throwable: response.body().close()
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.getStackTraceForCloseable(Platform.java:148)
at okhttp3.RealCall.captureCallStackTrace(RealCall.java:89)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:73)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:40)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340)
at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.implementation.KeyVaultClientBaseImpl.getKey(KeyVaultClientBaseImpl.java:1390)
at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.implementation.KeyVaultClientCustomImpl.getKey(KeyVaultClientCustomImpl.java:627)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.getAKVKeySize(SQLServerColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.java:565)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.decryptColumnEncryptionKey(SQLServerColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.java:165)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerSymmetricKeyCache.getKey(SQLServerSymmetricKeyCache.java:157)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerSecurityUtility.decryptSymmetricKey(SQLServerSecurityUtility.java:136)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.getParameterEncryptionMetadata(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:940)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:562)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:522)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2935)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:471)
```

Following is the code where we are establishing connection with Azure Key Vault to initiate DB Column encryption.

```
public void setupEncryption() throws Exception {
    if (alwaysOnEncryptionEnabled) {
        SQLServerColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider akvProvider = new SQLServerColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(this.alwaysOnEncryptionClientId, this.alwaysOnEncryptionClientSecret);
        Map<String, SQLServerColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider> keyStoreMap = new HashMap<>();
        keyStoreMap.put(akvProvider.getName(), akvProvider);
        SQLServerConnection.registerColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(keyStoreMap);

    }
}
```

It seems like in Azure Key Vault code connection is not closed correctly.

Please help me out to handle this warning message.

We want to handle this message because the application in which we are using Azure Key vault is very critical and doesn't want to have any vulnerability.

Also Want to know what could be the impact if we are unable to handle this connection leak.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try to add this line in your code:

```
keyVaultClient.httpClient().connectionPool().evictAll();
```

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-keyvault-java/issues/81) is a issue similar to yours' for your reference.

Comment: I can't use this solution because we are using SQLServerColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider() and we don't have much control over keyVaultClient object to close the connection.